# Probability of event in join sample space of X & Y

Tags: probability, random-variables, solution-verification

[image]

From what I understand, the answer should be $(0.1+0.35+0.05)$, since the given points have probability summation $1$. Am I correct? By the way, the correct answer unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.   That the probabilities of those four data points sum to one indicates that they are most certainly all of the possible outcomes.   Then:

$$\mathsf P\{X\leq 3\} = \mathsf P_{X,Y}(1,1)+\mathsf P_{X,Y}(2,2)+\mathsf P_{X,Y}(3,3)\qquad\color{red}{\checkmark}$$